# Lim Inf and Lim Sup of Collection of Sets

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, limsup-and-liminf

Folland defines
$$\limsup E_n=\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{n=k}^{\infty}E_n,\liminf E_n=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{n=k}^{\infty}E_n.$$
And states that $\limsup E_n=\{x:x\in E_n$ for infinitely many $n$},
$\liminf E_n= \{x:x\in E_n$ for all but finitely many $n$}

Is not "all but finitely many"="infinite"?

$\{E_n\}$ is infinite family.

Comment: No, there are infinitely many even numbers, but there are also infinitely many odd numbers. So if a point is in all even-indexed sets, but in no odd-indexed set,it is in infinitely many sets, but it's not in "all but finitely many" sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set of even numbers is infinite, but it is not "all but finitely many" of the integers.  So:  let $E_n = \{1,2\}$ for all even $n$ and $E_n = \{2,3\}$ for all odd $n$, and try computing liminf and limsup.